# How to send variable by href to route and received by controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

This is my Blade

```
<a data href="/Detail/{{$FT->Folder_ID}}">
Link
</a>
```

This is my Route

```
Route::get('/Detail/{{$FT->Folder_ID}}','DetailController@index');
```

and this is my cotroller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 class DetailController extends Controller
 {
    //
    public function index($request){
        dd($request);
    }
 }
```

i was wondering, if i can send the variable(folder_ID) so the controller can do some function with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your route :

```
Route::get('/Detail/{folder_ID}','DetailController@index');
```

And in the index method :

```
public function index($folder_ID){
    dd($folder_ID);
}
```

Comment: can you help me 1 more time?
when the DD already true,
when i return my view('Detail')
the link shows that Mywebsitename.com/Detail/1 (folder_id)
and the view is broken(without)css

Answer (score 1):

Find below code snippets. This could work fine with your requirement.

Your Blade Code:

```
<a data href="/Detail/{{$FT->Folder_ID}}"> Link </a>
```

Your Corrected Route Code:

```
Route::get('/Detail/{{$id}}','DetailController@index');
```

Your Controller :

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 class DetailController extends Controller
 {
    public function index($id){
     dd($id);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For sending a variable concatenate this to your url:

```
www.xyz.com/controller_name?id=Folder_ID
```

In the above url Folder_ID is a variable and will dynamically fetch the value from the link that is clicked.

now you can use the variable id in the controller using :

```
$_GET['id'];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: how can i concatenate those things?

Comment: using the dot(.) operator :-

url().'?id='.$folder_id;

where url contains your default site url and $folder_id is a dynamic variable

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple and clear. Following is the example how i use it.
give name to your route like this
**ROUTE**

```
Route::get('/tutor_approval/{id}','DashboardController@tutor_approval')->name('tutor_approval');
```

Now your anchor tag in something.blade.php. use route name in anchortag
**VIEW**

```
<a href="{{route('tutor_approval',['id' => 'tutor_id'])}}">approve</a>
```

**Controller**

```
public function tutor_approval($id){
        $values = array('admin_approval' => 1);
        $update = Tutor::where('tutor_id', $id)->update($values);
        return \Response::json(array('success' => true), 200);
}
```